# parssing registration ID for push notification on login API

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, sharedpreferences

Hi am running with an issue that i need to parse my registration id to my server threw API where am getting my registration id in splash screen activity and after i pass that value to login activity. In login activity am adding registration id to shared preference and after trying to send the value in doinbackground by getting the saved value from shared preference. while parsing first time am successfully getting registration ID from shared preference but when i logout and try to login again my registration id is parsing default value "id".

Loginactivity.java

```
    package com.driverapp.inis.zuber;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import Connectivity_manager.Httpmanager;
import Connectivity_manager.Internet_CheckingActivity;
import Session_manager.SessionManager;
import UI_Alert.AlertDialogManager;
import UI_Alert.TransparentProgressDialog;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnlogin;
    private EditText txtusername;
    private EditText txtpassword;
    private String userName;
    private String message;
    private String userid;
    private JSONArray login_data = null;
    private Internet_CheckingActivity chckInternt;
    private TransparentProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static final String URL_Login = "http://myapi;
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private static final String TAG_username = "username";
    private static final String TAG_password = "password";
    SessionManager msessionManager;
    private AlertDialogManager alert;
    private Location newLocation = null;
    private static final String TAG = "SplashScreenActivity";
    private  GeoLocationFinder geoLocationFinder;
    private static final String TAG_regid = "gcm_regid";
private String regid;
    private String regId = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        alert = new AlertDialogManager();
        chckInternt = new Internet_CheckingActivity(this);
        txtusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lusername);
        txtpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lpassword);
        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
        msessionManager = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(mbtnLogin);
        regid= getIntent().getStringExtra("regig");
        msessionManager.setregid("registrationid",regid);
       regId = msessionManager.getregistration("registrationid","id");


//        if (SERVER_URL == null || SENDER_ID == null || SERVER_URL.length() == 0
//                || SENDER_ID.length() == 0) {
//            // GCM sernder id / server url is missing
//            alert.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Configuration Error!",
//                    "Please set your Server URL and GCM Sender ID", false);
//            // stop executing code by return
//            return;
//        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Splashscreen.class));
    }
      private View.OnClickListener mbtnLogin = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (chckInternt.isNetworkAvailable() == true) {
                    if (txtusername.getText().toString().isEmpty() || txtpassword.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Login failed", "Both Username and Password required", false);
                        txtusername.setText("");
                        txtpassword.setText("");

                    } else {

                        setupLocation();
                    }
                } else {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Login failed", "Please check your internet Connection and Retry Again", false);
                    txtusername.setText("");
                    txtpassword.setText("");
                }
            }
        };
    private void setupLocation() {
        GeoLocationFinder.LocationResult locationResult = new GeoLocationFinder.LocationResult() {

            @Override
            public void gotLocation(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {

                    newLocation = new Location(location);
                    newLocation.set(location);

                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "Got coordinates, congratulations. Longitude = "
                                    + newLocation.getLongitude() + " Latitude = "
                                    + newLocation.getLatitude());
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            new AttemptLogin().execute();
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            alert.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Check Your GPS", "Restart your Application", false);


                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        geoLocationFinder = new GeoLocationFinder();
        geoLocationFinder.getLocation(this, locationResult);
    }

        @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        txtusername.setText("");
        txtpassword.setText("");
    }
    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new TransparentProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this,R.drawable.spinner);
            pDialog.setCancelable(Boolean.FALSE);
            pDialog.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


            Httpmanager hm = new Httpmanager();
            final String username = txtusername.getText().toString();
            String password = txtpassword.getText().toString();
            List params1 = new ArrayList();
            params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_username, username));
            params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_password, password));
            params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_regid, regId));
            Log.d("regid", regId);
            String jsonstr = hm.makeServiceCall(URL_Login, Httpmanager.post, params1);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonstr);
            if (jsonstr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
                   if (jsonObject.getString("hasError").equals("1")) {
                        message = jsonObject.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                alert.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Alert", message, false);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        message = jsonObject.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                        login_data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < login_data.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject l = login_data.getJSONObject(i);
                            userName = l.getString("username");
                            userid = l.getString("userid");
                            msessionManager.createLoginSession(userName, userid);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DefaultMAP.class);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message + userName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("HttpManager", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please check your internet Connection and Retry Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            txtusername.setText("");
            txtpassword.setText("");
        }
    }
    }
```

Splashscreen.java

```
    package com.driverapp.inis.zuber;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import java.io.IOException;

import Connectivity_manager.Internet_CheckingActivity;
import UI_Alert.AlertDialogManager;


public class Splashscreen extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "SplashScreenActivity";
    private static final String TAG1 = "lifecycle";
    private Location newLocation = null;
    private AlertDialogManager alert;
    private Internet_CheckingActivity chckInternt;
    private GeoLocationFinder geoLocationFinder;
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    protected String SENDER_ID = "525761298572";
    private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = null;
    private String regid = null;
    private Context context = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
        alert = new AlertDialogManager();
        chckInternt = new Internet_CheckingActivity(this);
        Log.d(TAG1, "oncreate");
        context = getApplication();
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        restart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG1, "onresume");
        //  setupLocation();
        if (chckInternt.isNetworkAvailable() == true) {
            setupLocation();
        } else {
            alert.showAlertDialog(Splashscreen.this, "Error", "Please Check Your Internet Connection", false);
        }

        checkPlayServices();
    }

    /**
     * Method for checking the current lat log values.
     */
    private void setupLocation() {
        GeoLocationFinder.LocationResult locationResult = new GeoLocationFinder.LocationResult() {

            @Override
            public void gotLocation(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {

                    newLocation = new Location(location);
                    newLocation.set(location);

                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "Got coordinates, congratulations. Longitude = "
                                    + newLocation.getLongitude() + " Latitude = "
                                    + newLocation.getLatitude());
                    Intent i = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, DefaultMAP.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            alert.showAlertDialog(Splashscreen.this, "Check Your GPS", "Restart your Application", false);


                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        geoLocationFinder = new GeoLocationFinder();
        geoLocationFinder.getLocation(this, locationResult);

        RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash);
        root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                restart();
            }
        });

    }

    public void restart() {
        Intent rIntent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
        rIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(rIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG1, "onpause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG1, "onstart");
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "This device is not supported - Google Play Services.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Registration ID not found.");
            return "";
        }
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.d(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        return getSharedPreferences(Splashscreen.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }


    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask() {

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Current Device's Registration ID is: " + regid);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    regid = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("regig", regid);
                Splashscreen.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            };

        } .execute(null,null,null);
    }
}
```

Sessionmanager.java

```
    package Session_manager;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import com.driverapp.inis.zuber.LoginActivity;
import com.driverapp.inis.zuber.Splashscreen;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class SessionManager {
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "name";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

    // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "username";

    // Reg Id for GCM (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_Regid = "regid";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "userid";

    //trip id
    public static final String Key_trip = "trip_id";

    // Constructor
    public SessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(_context);//_context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    /**
     * Create login session
     * */
    public void createLoginSession(String name, String id){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);


        // Storing id in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_ID, id);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

    //create trip id

    public void tripid(String tid){
        editor.putString(Key_trip,tid);
        editor.commit();
    }

    //get stored data for trip id

    public HashMap<String,String> gettripid(){
        HashMap<String,String>tid = new HashMap<String,String>();
        tid.put(Key_trip,pref.getString(Key_trip,null));
        return tid;
    }

    /**
     * Create RegId session
     * */
    public void createRegIdSession(String regid){
//        // Storing login value as TRUE
//        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_Regid, regid);
        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything
     * */
    public void checkLogin(){
        // Check login status
        if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }
    /**
     * Get stored session data
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        HashMap<String, String> id = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user name
        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));

        // user email id

        user.put(KEY_ID, pref.getString(KEY_ID, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Get stored session data for regid
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserregidDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user name
        user.put(KEY_Regid, pref.getString(KEY_Regid, null));
        return user;
    }
    /**
     * Clear session details
     * */
    public void logoutUser(){
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Splashscreen.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Quick check for login
     * **/
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);

    }

    public String getString(String key, String defaultVal){
        return pref.getString(key, defaultVal);
    }

    public String getregistration(String key, String dvalue){
        return pref.getString(key,dvalue);
    }

    public void setregid(String key,String value){
    Editor editor1 = pref.edit();
        editor1.putString(key, value);
//      editor.apply();
        editor1.commit();
    }

    public void setString(String key, String value){
        Editor e = pref.edit();
        e.putString(key, value);
        e.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the first paragraph you have written, don't you think that's awfully complicated?

Comment: I think that in your `Sessionmanager.java` 's method ` public void logoutUser`, you clean all the data from `shared preferences`  which is the issue. Then you try to login again my registration id is parsing default value "id", because it cannot find the value and use the default value instead.